# 360 view using multiple uiimages - (from different angles)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, panorama-control, 360-degrees

I want to do a 360 view of an object,something like [this](http://www.gsmarena.com/apple_iphone_5c-3d-spin-5690.php)
I have 72 images of that object from different required angles.
I saw some tutorial with sample code somewhere, but now I forgot that. Can some one give me a good tutorial for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need [FVImageSequence](https://github.com/jaunce/FVImageSequenceDemo)

[original Post](http://www.fvalente.org/blog/2011/12/19/fvimagesequence-for-mac-os-xios/)

hope that helps.